# Why Ubuntu12.04.2 reboot automatically?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, reboot, cups

Recently, I installed Ubuntu-server 12.04.2 LTS on our new bought server. It runs well until this morning it reboot automatically. And all running programs is missing.
Why it will automatically reboot? Is it hardware problems? I've looked about system log quite a long time, but can't figure out something helpful? Can any body help?

It reboot around 6:42. Here is some Log from /var/log:

/var/log/

```
May 31 06:42:04 iipl2013 sshd[1174]: Server listening on :: port 22.
May 31 06:42:04 iipl2013 sshd[1174]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
May 31 06:42:04 iipl2013 sshd[1174]: Received signal 15; terminating.
May 31 06:42:04 iipl2013 sshd[1499]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
May 31 06:42:04 iipl2013 sshd[1499]: Server listening on :: port 22.
May 31 06:42:06 iipl2013 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
May 31 06:42:06 iipl2013 lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
May 31 06:42:08 iipl2013 lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "all"
May 31 06:42:08 iipl2013 dbus[1187]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.23" (uid=111 pid=2539 comm="/usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-ser") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.14" (uid=0 pid=1977 comm="/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon ")
May 31 07:17:01 iipl2013 CRON[3348]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 31 07:17:01 iipl2013 CRON[3348]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

/var/log/syslog

```
May 31 06:47:05 iipl2013 anacron[1827]: Job `cron.daily' started
May 31 06:47:05 iipl2013 anacron[3044]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2013-05-31
May 31 06:47:11 iipl2013 kernel: [  324.097505] audit_printk_skb: 69 callbacks suppressed
May 31 06:47:11 iipl2013 kernel: [  324.097512] type=1400 audit(1369954031.407:35): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1229 comm="cupsd" pid=1229 comm="cupsd" capability=36  capname="block_suspend"
May 31 07:00:02 iipl2013 kernel: [ 1093.560934] type=1400 audit(1369954802.071:36): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1229 comm="cupsd" pid=1229 comm="cupsd" capability=36  capname="block_suspend"
```

Does the reboot affected by "cups", "lightdm" or "xrdp"? 
Any ideas?